# How and where to add unleash-client for asp.net and node.js angular typescript application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core, featuretoggle

I am trying to add https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-client-node to node js angular project. I am not a developer but just want integrate feature toggle in one of my projects. The application tech stack contains asp.net core, nodejs, angular and type script. What is the exact location(file) to configure the unleash-client so that I can see the application in the server. I have tried many ways and terribly failed due to my naive coding skills. Can some on give some more details on the integration.

Comment: very open-ended question!!

Comment: I can give more details, have you worked with unleash feature toggle?

Comment: what about a link to your project...the particular section of the code you want to modify. I suggest you read-up on Unleash. in the link you gave read the ReadMe given in that same page... so if you have any question while doing what you were told, you can post the defaulting code!!

Comment: https://unleash.github.io/docs/client_sdk has all the answers, just look it up!!, and there is a simple example  in it's "getting started" link  https://unleash.github.io/docs/getting_started

Comment: @Damilola I am not able to understand where to add that piece of code. componets.ts, modules.ts, main.ts or create a new file.ts Can you please give me more detailed process if possible.